# Current date minus n days formatted 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Tags: javascript, date

I am try to get in javascript the current date minus some delta days and format the result to mm/dd/yyyy.
I write this piece of code:

```
  <script>
     function deltadata(d_delta) {
         var d = new Date();

         d.setDate(d.getDate() - d_delta);
         var dd = String(d).padStart(2, '0');
         var mm = String(d.getMonth +1).padStart(2, '0');
         var yyyy = d.getFullYear();

         today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

         return today;
       }
  </script>
```

but the result is not what I expected

`function getMonth() { [native code] }1/Wed Feb 19 2020 12:45:49 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)/2020`

someone can help me, please?

so many thanks in advance

Comment: `var mm = String(d.getMonth +1)` – you wanted to _call_ `getMonth` there, but you forgot to include the `()` that actually do that …

Comment: And `var dd = String(d).padStart(2, '0');` appears completely wrong, you are operating on the string representation of the full Date object here - this should use `getDate`, same as the next line uses / tried to use `getMonth` …

Comment: And `var dd = String(d).padStart(2, '0')` should be `var dd = String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may employ `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` for that purpose, specifying format options accordingly:

```js
const deltaDate = n => {
  const today = new Date()
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - n)
  return today
    .toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month:'2-digit',day:'2-digit',year:'numeric'})
}

console.log(deltaDate(3))
```